# Help me plot a tangent with a Sin curve

Tags: plotting

Hi just wondering how to graph the tangent as well as this curve on the same graph : f(x)= Sin[x] at x=0 where the gradient of the tangent is 1

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Do you mean like `Plot[{Sin[x], x}, {x, -\[Pi], \[Pi]}]`? Or are you looking for an automated way to construct such plots for arbitrary $f$?

Comment: For an automated way, you could do `plotTangent[f_, x0_] := 
 Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], Normal@Series[f[x], {x, x0, 1}]}], {x, x0 - 4, 
   x0 + 4}]`, and then call `plotTangent[f, 0]`, which produces the desired graph.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some fun:

```
    Manipulate[
       Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], Normal@Series[f[x], {x, x0, 1}]}], 
       {x, -5, 5},
       PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-2, 2}},
       Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{x0, f[x0]}]}],
    {{x0, 0}, -4, 4},
    {f, {Sin, Cos, Tan, 1/4 #^2 & -> "x^2/4"}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using derivative.

```
tangent[f_,x0_]:=(f^\[Prime])[x0] #1+First[b/. NSolve[f[x0]==(f^\[Prime])[x0] x0+b,b]]&;
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[{f[x], tangent[f, x0][x]}], {x, -5, 5}, 
      PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-2, 2}}, 
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{x0, f[x0]}]}], {x0, -5, 
      5}, {f, {Sin, Cos,(.2 #^2 - 1.5) &}}]
```

Comment: `tangent` appears to be undefined.