# Plotting a tangent line

Tags: plotting

I have to plot a function and the tangent line and I don't know how to do it. It has to be one plot

function: f[x_]= Sin[x] and the tangent line for the function is x=0

Other questions didn't help me so I need some help.

Comment: See https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/74015/help-me-plot-a-tangent-with-a-sin-curve and https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18090/sliding-a-tangent-line-along-a-curve

Comment: To get up and running with calculus using Mathematica a good reference is [Mathematica by Example](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematica-Example-Martha-L-Abell/dp/0128124814).

Comment: Those don't work, already looked at them